# How to set vrf forwarding for interface in cisco ios via ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, cisco-ios

In my playbook I need to set up a new l3 interface and configure *vrf forwarding* for it. In cisco.nxos there is the cisco.nxos.nxos_vrf_interface which manages interface specific VRF configuration.

I can not find equivalent module for cisco.ios. Is there any? The cisco.ios.ios_vrf manages VRF definitions, but does not manage the interface configuration. The *interfaces* parameter does not add a new interface to the list but replaces the existing list.

Is there some way how to achieve similar behavior as in cisco.nxos.nxos_vrf_interface for cisco.ios? Or any workaround, how to manage iterface specific VRF configuration in cisco.ios?